# pgfplots: extra x tick; tick length; affecting axis label position

Tags: pgfplots

- I want to have an `extra x tick`.
- In my "real" example, it is needed that the `extra x tick label` is moved in `-y` direction (using `major tick length`).
- `pgfplots` cleverly also moves the `xlabel` in `-y` direction automatically.
- This normally desriable behavior is a problem in my special case.
- **Question:** Can I prevent that the position of the `xlabel` is affected by `major tick length`? I do *not* want to manually use `xlabel shift = -20pt,` because in my real example this still causes a minor difference.

---

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line= bottom,
        axis y line= left,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
        extra x ticks = {-5},
        extra x tick style = {
            major tick length = 20pt, % <-- Relevant
            xtick align = outside,    % <-- Relevant
            }
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line= bottom,
        axis y line= left,  
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x +4$},
        extra x ticks = {-5},
    ]
    % use TeX as calculator:
    \addplot {x^2 - x +4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, because you need to take into account the normal major tick length as well ...

To prove that this works, comment the two lines starting with `xlabel style` and `extra x ticks` and take a close look when the PDF updates. You shouldn't notice a jump in the xlabel position.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        % store the extra tick length in a variable, so you don't need to repeat yourself
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\ExtraMajorTickLength}{20pt}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel={$f(x) = x^2 - x + 4$},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % this gives you the "correct" xlabel positioning
        % (the `/2` is needed, because the normal ticks are centered and thus
        %  only half of the tick length is below the x-axis line)
        xlabel style={
            yshift={\ExtraMajorTickLength + \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length}/2},
        },
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        extra x ticks={-5},
        extra x tick style={
            major tick length=\ExtraMajorTickLength,
            xtick align=outside,
        },
    ]
        \addplot {x^2 - x + 4};
    \end{axis}
        % (for debugging purposes only to not change the size of the `tikzpicture`
        %  when commenting lines as stated in the text)
        \fill [red] (0,-1.2) circle [radius=1pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks! I saw in the manual that the default length is `1.5mm` but I wasn't sure what to do with that information :). Your solution is very elegant - thx!

Comment: As always: You are welcome!